# Нужна помощь с Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не переносится база на Heroku. При `heroku run rake db:migrate`
Вот мой Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'rails_12factor'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'

end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'


# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc



group :development, :test do

  gem 'debugger'
end

group :development do


  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'


  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Гем `pg` должен быть в группе `production`.

Вместо

```
gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
```

Нужно

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
end
```